# Getting an infinite loop trying to read a text file by tokenizing the string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, text-files, token

I am trying to read a text file line by line and tokenize them into elements of a struck using custom function. Yet I get an infinite loop trying to do so. My code is as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
   char barcodeNumber[5];
   char title[50]; char author[30];
   char publisherCompany[30];
   int publishingYear;
   char isbn[13];
} Book;

Book booklist[100];

void readBooks()
{
    int i = 0;
    char line[255];

    printf("asd");
    FILE *libraryPtr;

    libraryPtr = fopen("books.txt", "r");
    if (libraryPtr == NULL)
        printf("File not found.\n");
    else
    {
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), libraryPtr) != NULL)
        {

            booklist[i].barcodeNumber = strtok(line, ";");
            booklist[i].title = strtok(NULL, ";");
            booklist[i].author = strtok(NULL, ";");
            booklist[i].publisherCompany = strtok(NULL, ";");
            booklist[i].publishingYear = strtok(NULL, ";");
            booklist[i].isbn = strtok(NULL, ";");
            i++;
        }
    }
    fclose(libraryPtr);
    printf("%s", booklist[1].barcodeNumber);
}
```

My input file is (Books.txt):

```
A1234;Elements of Theory of Computation;Harry R. Lewis;Prentice Hall;1998;2132457198219
A1987;Knowledge Acquisiton;Karen L. McGraw;Prentice Hall;1989;1945868279220
M3158;Artificial Intelligence;Patrick H. Winston;Addison Wesley;1992;3243568791940
C8287;Linux Sistem Yonetimi;Tom Adelstein;O'Reilly;2007;1718295464178
E6097;CRYPTOGRAPHY AND NETWORK SECURITY PRINCIPLES;William Stallings;Prentice Hall;2007;9780136097044
```

Comment: can you try with `while(1){...` and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Be aware that you are reusing `line` for each iteration through the loop, so you're not properly collecting unique array items for each `i`. `strtok` is just returning pointers to locations within `line`. Where and how is `booklist` defined?

Comment: Publish full code at http://ideone.com/

Comment: Booklist is defined at the beginning of the code so it could be defined as a global variable 'typedef struct{
char barcodeNumber[5];
char title[50];
char author[30];
char publisherCompany[30];
int publishingYear;
char isbn[13];
} Book;

Book booklist[100];'

Comment: The code you presented does not loop infinitely for me (given a suitable global declaration for `booklist`).

Comment: Also, take heed of @lurker's comment.  Although the code you presented does not loop infinitely, it is not going to accomplish what you want.

Comment: @AhmetUmutDurmuş what do you mean it *could* be defined? It either is or isn't. Can you please show the appropriate code in your problem so it's readable, and not in a comment, where it isn't?

Comment: I could not really understand why 'strtok' is not returning values to booklist arrays? Oh, and also he following error is given when I try to compile the program:  76 43 C:\Users\Ahmet\Desktop\CENG 301\301 odev.cpp [Error] 'strtok' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Read the manual page on `strtok` carefully. And check what header files are required to use it. How many lines are in your `books.txt` file? If there are more than 100, then that will be trouble. Did you read my other comment about your use of `line` and `strtok`?

Comment: Ok thanks, let me read the manual and try again.

Comment: @AhmetUmutDurmus , Did you include `string.h`?

Comment: @ CoolGuy I did include `string.h`. Now I get a different error:`[Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'char*' to 'char [5]'`. @lurker I did read your other comment but did not get it. Sorry for noobing guys just started taking my first programming course 4 weeks ago. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You can't assign a character pointer to an array variable. C is kind of low level. It doesn't figure out what you're trying to do. It tries to do exactly what you tell it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in C are not like in some high level language, you cannot somply assign strings with the `=` operator. A complete explanation is beyond the scope of this answer.

You need this inside your while loop (minumum code, no error checking and/or bounds checking done here).

```
   strcpy(booklist[i].barcodeNumber, strtok(line, ";"));
   strcpy(booklist[i].title, strtok(NULL, ";"));
   strcpy(booklist[i].author, strtok(NULL, ";"));
   strcpy(booklist[i].publisherCompany, strtok(NULL, ";"));
   char *pyear = strtok(NULL, ";");
   booklist[i].publishingYear = atol(pyear);
   strcpy(booklist[i].isbn, strtok(NULL, ";"));
   i++;
```

Id didn't test the code, but it should at least give you an idea.

For `atol` you also need to include:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

**EDIT**:

```
char barcodeNumber[5];
```

should be

```
char barcodeNumber[6];
```

You need space for the terminating zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code fragment replacing some of your function code. The errors were due trying to write the `strok` pointer to a string, instead of copying the string. Apart from being the wrong type, the string pointers became invalid once you moved on to the next line. I also tweaked the way you did the year integer field, and limited the string lengths and the array size `i` too.

```
char *ptr;
Book *bookptr;
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), libraryPtr) != NULL && i < 100) {
    bookptr = &booklist[i];

    ptr = strtok(line, ";");
    if (ptr)
        strncpy (bookptr->barcodeNumber, ptr, sizeof(bookptr->barcodeNumber)-1);

    // etc...

    ptr = strtok(NULL, ";");
    if (ptr)
        bookptr->publishingYear = atoi (ptr);

    // etc...
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Just behind @Michael Walz!